# Sortedness of Bolt DB items

Tags: go, queue, boltdb

I am planning on implementing a queue and persisting the objects into a Bolt DB instance. I was wondering how to determine the sortedness of the items when reloading my application and determining head/tail.

To quote the Bolt DB project on insertion of items to a bucket:

> Bolt stores its keys in byte-sorted order within a bucket

So basically the keys for the DB are byte [arrays] and sorted. I see an implementation online that uses the following line to convert an int to a byte array in little endian.

```
key := make([]byte, 8)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(key, id)
```

What other ways are there to convert the keys to byte arrays for sortedness?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using `NextSequence` to generate keys, they'll already be in order.

Comment: @Adrian sweet? Shall I still convert that uint64 to byte array using the Big endian function? Thanks